# Issue commands at the same time in several terminals

Tags: terminal

Desktop -> ssh -> Servers

Are there any solutions to have several windows in my desktop and:

- If I issue a command in one window, the same command thing will be issued on other terminals too. So if I give out a "chmod" command in one terminal on a server, then ex.: 3 other servers will have the same commands in 3 other windows that I can see. Like if I would have several keyboards..

I know there is a solution for this, I just don't know what is the name of it.

Comment: I've been used clusterssh as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to use [terminator](http://gnometerminator.blogspot.com/p/introduction.html) a lot when I did network demos. It lets you create multiple windows and group some or all of the windows then you can have your key strokes go to all of the windows at the same time. You can use this to start separate instances at almost the same time, or enter the same command to different machines, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`clush`.  Likely in RPM "clustershell".

```
clush(1) - Linux man page

Name

clush - execute shell commands on a cluster

clush -a | -g group | -w nodes [OPTIONS] command
```